# DOS BOX Screen resolution problem

Tags: 12.04, graphics, resolution, dosbox

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I installed DOSBOX using `apt-get install doxbox`command and configured TC in DOSBOX properly. Everything is working fine, but when we it goes to full screen mode of DOSBOX then it changes the resolution of the screen and it may happen, that DOXBOX is closed unexpectedly, because I can't see its process on the launcher after going to full screen mode.

After trying 2-3 times DOSBOX is going to FULL SCREEN mode properly, but on exiting same problem is remaining.

[image: My Desktop before opening DOSBOX]
[image: My Desktop on exit the DOSBOX]

I am using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch the full Screen mode in DOSBOX

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

You can edit and then adjust the screen resolution for DosBox window in:

```
/home/username/.dosbox/dosbox-0.7x.conf
```

Please see **Line 27** `windowresolution=value` - simple change the value as suggested from `320x240` to whatever you want, then save the .conf-file. (Please make a backup copy of the original .conf, before changing anything, just in case!!)

**See list of possible value options available**:

- Use `fullscreen=true` for full screen
- Use `fullscreen=false` for DOSBox in a window
- Change `fullresolution=original` to `fullresolution=desktop`
- When using a window, change `windowresolution=original` to `windowresolution=1280x1024` (or use 1024x768 for a smaller window)
- Change `output=surface` to `output=openglnb` (uses graphics hardware and maintains crisp image with scaling).
- You might try `output=ddraw`, which in some cases has a lower CPU load.
  Scroll down to the [render] section
- Change `aspect=false` to `aspect=true` (maintains 4:3 aspect ratio, otherwise keep on false if you like the aspect ratio of your screen, mostly 16:9 or 16:10 nowadays)
- Save the configuration file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (or File - Save)
  (Re)start DOSBox.

[image: dosBox]

For more detail please refer to: [dosboxWiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf) | [dosboxScreen-resolution](http://www.dosgamers.com/dos/dosbox-dos-emulator/screen-resolution) | [Manual Instructions](http://www.smartluck.com/faq/faq444.htm)

Answer (score 2):

After using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the only way to restore your initial resolution is to open the Displays properties (Open first System Settings).

After closing Dosbox, my display resolution was 1152x864, I just had to select 1920x1200 to recover my initial resolution.

Depending on how Dosbox lower your resolution, you could open the Displays settings before starting Dosbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a fix.
Changing the following values in dosbox.conf as below worked for me.

```
fullresolution=desktop
windowresolution=desktop
output=overlay
```